What is the single line waveform of a resolver of sin or cos output？
For a resolver, the excitation signal is about 10kHz sin waveform. And the output are two pairs of differential ports: sin+/- and cos+/-.
If I test the output signal(such as sin+/-) by using a differential probe ,the output waveform is standard curves. But if I test a single sin+ or sin- by using a general single ended probe , the waveform of sin+/sin- to gnd（in a PCB board） signal will be now big and then small in amplitude.
See picture below:

Blue channel is the sin+ waveform, yellow channel is sin- waveform.
So can anyone share your oscilloscope waveform of a resolver sin+ or sin- or cos+,cos- single ended signal?

What does "signal will be now big and the small in amplitude." mean? Please edit your question to clarify.

Your scope also plots the difference in voltage between the probe tip and ground. What is the ground lead connected to? How is that related to the resolver outputs? Also what is the revolver output connected to, apart from the scope - is it floating?

Add a MATH channel, set the operator to "subtract" and operation to C1 - C3. See if the result is the same (or at least similar) as the one you get with a diff probe.

How are the outputs wired? Bias offset ? https://i.sstatic.net/0DZqiaCY.png https://www.analog.com/en/resources/analog-dialogue/articles/precision-rtdc-measures-angular-position-and-velocity.html

Note that the outputs should be "differential".
